# Redefining cases command

Tags: cases

I do not like that `\begin{cases} \end{cases}` only allows for one alignment tab, as I usually want to use two.

```
\left\{
\begin{array}{rlr}
  a & = c & x=1 \\
  b & = d & x=2 1 
\end{array}
\right.
```

Is it possible to redefine `cases` (or define a new environment) such that I could just write

```
\begin{mycases} 
     a & = c & x=1\\ 
     b & = d & x=2
\end{mycases}
```

or something similarly simple?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply use your own definition as a new environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newenvironment{mycases}%
  {\left\{
   \begin{array}{@{}r@{\;}lr@{}}
  }%
  {\end{array}
   \right.
  }

\(\begin{mycases} 
     a & = c & x=1\\ 
     b & = d & x=2
  \end{mycases}
\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!

Comment: @flawr Try with `cases` and `mycases` side by side

Comment: @egreg Are you referring to the distance between the left brace and the first column? You are right, there was too much space, I removed it.

Comment: Also the vertical spacing is different

Answer (score 8):

Yes. Use `alignat` and `empheq`(needless to load `amsmath` in this case):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{alignat*=2}
  a & = c, &\qquad x&=1,\\
  b + b’ & = d + d’, & x&=2.
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

Note you need `3&`. More generally, for `n` groups of alignment, you need `2n–1` ampersands: one is for the new group (from the 2nd group), the next for the alignment point inside the group.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Yes, just modify suitably the definition of `cases`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{mycases}{%
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \left\lbrace
  \def\arraystretch{1.2}%
  \array{@{}r@{}>{{}}l@{\quad}l@{}}%
}{%
  \endarray\right.%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{mycases} 
a+a^2 & = c & x=1\\ 
b & = d-d^2 & x=2
\end{mycases}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this definition seems to be a little bit more complicated than the one @gernot posted. Is there a difference?

Comment: @flawr The definition is complicated, but the input style is simpler.